# Runtime Error: Structure for student details in C

Tags: c, runtime-error

This a C program using Structures to feed and display student details. When run the program goes through logical errors. I couldn't find the cause. Please help and if possible post the correct code.

Edit: I had segmentation fault earlier and then I edited the code according to one of the comments(@CiaPan) in this post and found that I still have logical errors when running the code.

```
      #include <stdio.h>

      struct student
      {
      char name[100];
      int roll,mark[100];
      float average;
      }a[100];

      int main()

      {
      int n,i,j,m,sum;
      printf("enter the no. of students and no. of subjects : \n");
      scanf("\n%d\n%d",&n,&m); 
      printf("enter the student details : \n");
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)

      {   
      printf("\n%d",i+1);
      printf("\nenter the name :");
      scanf("%s",a[i].name);
      printf("\nenter the roll no.");
      scanf("%d",&a[i].roll);
      printf("\nmarks :\n");
      for(j=0;j<m;j++)
      {
      printf("%d.\t",j+1);
      scanf("%d\n",&a[i].mark[j]);
      }

      }    
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      { 
      sum=0;
      for(j=0;j<m;j++)
      sum=sum+a[i].mark[j];
           }
      for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
      a[i].average=sum/m;

      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      if(a[i].average>=75)
      printf("\n%s\n%d\n",a[i].name,a[i].roll);
      return 0;

      }
```

**I solved this problem.**

Edit2: I was getting some errors in output.There was a error in scanf function used for getting marks,which i corrected as shown.Also there was problem with calculating average due to a logical error associated with for loops.

```
 //Correct code

 #include <stdio.h>

      struct student
      {
      char name[100];
      int roll,mark[100];
      float average;
      }a[100];

      int main()

      {
      int n,i,j,m,sum;
      printf("enter the no. of students and no. of subjects : \n");
      scanf("\n%d\n%d",&n,&m); 
      printf("enter the student details : \n");
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)

      {   
      printf("\n%d",i+1);
      printf("\nenter the name :");
      scanf("%s",a[i].name);
      printf("\nenter the roll no.");
      scanf("%d",&a[i].roll);
      printf("\nmarks :\n");
      for(j=0;j<m;j++)
      {
      printf("%d.\t",j+1);
      scanf("\n%d",&a[i].mark[j]);
      }

      }   



      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      { 
        sum=0;
      for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        sum=sum+a[i].mark[j];



      //for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
      a[i].average=sum/m;
      }


      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      if(a[i].average>=75)
      printf("\n%s\n%d\n",a[i].name,a[i].roll);
      return 0;

      }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The screenshot you mentioned is missing. And Please do not add it here. Whatever is related to a segfault, can easily be added as pure text. BTW: Without showing us your code (text within the question) no one will be able to help.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your code. I suggest you look up on a basic C tutorial once again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I have edited the code but still got some run time issues. The compiler though didn't show any errors.

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` function needs to know where to store data it inputs. To do that, it needs to get *pointers to variables* to receive data. Hence you must pass *pointers to your `int` variables*, not values of those variables:

```
    scanf( "%d%d", &n, &m );
```

instead of

```
    scanf( "%d%d", n, m );
```

Same for inputting marks.

On the other hand, the array's name decays to a pointer to the first item of the array, so when you need to input a chracter string, you should pass the array variable:

```
    scanf( "%s...", a[i].name, ... );
```

instead of

```
    scanf( "%s...", &a[i].name, ... );
```

because `&a[i].name` is a *pointer to the array*, while you need a pointer to the *first character* of the array here.

Additionally, when summing marks, you should reset the `sum` to zero for each student. Otherwise for each student except the first one you accumulate marks of all previous students.

Plus you should test the return values from `scanf` to make sure the input data were read successfully, and possibly test them for consistency (e.g., your program would accept negative marks...).

Comment: Thank you ! CiaPan

Comment: I edited as said by you and got running the code, but still got some errors. pls help.